# Laravel form no data submitted

Tags: php, laravel

My form in my-profile.blade.php looks like this:

```
<form id="profile-form" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ route('myprofile.store') }}">
      <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="<?php echo csrf_token(); ?>">
      <div class="col-md-6">
          <label for="first_name">First Name</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="first_name" placeholder="First Name" value="{{$currentUser->first_name}}" required>
      </div>
...
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
</form>
```

web.php file:

```
Route::resource('myprofile', 'MyProfileController');
```

MyProfileController controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
        Log::info("request:");
        Log::info($request);
        Log::info("input:");
        Log::info(Input::all());
}
```

After logging the request and input:

```
local.INFO: request:  
[local.INFO: array (
  '_token' => 'S0u7OzktqMS5zVLr9WHwIq52EhGfZKoQWRD6XlCR',
)  
local.INFO: input:  
local.INFO: array (
  '_token' => 'S0u7OzktqMS5zVLr9WHwIq52EhGfZKoQWRD6XlCR',
)
```

This is what I get.
I also tried the {{csrf_token()}}, the output is the same.
The controller's store function runs, so the action is set up okay.
What could be the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there's no name attribute inside your input.

Comment: How couldn't I see it... Thank you for the answer it's okay now.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<form id="profile-form" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ route('myprofile.store') }}">
      {{csrf_field() }}
      <div class="col-md-6">
          <label for="first_name">First Name</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="first_name" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name" value="{{$currentUser->first_name}}" required>
      </div>

      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
</form>
```

Controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
     dd($request->get('first_name'));
}
```